How is "dash" in Chinese ? as a punctuation mark. Thank you
How is "dash" in Chinese ? As a punctuation mark.
Thank you

https://byjus.com/english/dash/

A dash is a punctuation mark that resembles a hyphen, but longer. A dash is used to separate part of a sentence and indicate a break.

https://learnsmart.edu.hk/%E6%A8%99%E9%BB%9E%E7%AC%A6%E8%99%9F/

破折號 (dash) —


主要表明行文中解釋説明的語句 - Statements that mainly indicate explanations in the text (to highlight the explanation by breaking it from the main clause)


Example:


海參吃海底的蟲子—浮游生物 - Sea cucumbers eat insects on the bottom of the sea - plankton)

破折 means "to break off", 破折號 serves to break a sentence to highlight the explanation or additional information

连接号相关
根据 https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E8%BF%9E%E6%8E%A5%E5%8F%B7 的介绍，dash作为标点符号表示连接号，注意 根据维基百科的介绍，连接号和破折号不是同一个符号，原因见下面的2张图片：
第一张图片：

第二张图片：

破折号相关
破折号的介绍看 https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E7%A0%B4%E6%8A%98%E5%8F%B7
第三张图片：

根据维基百科的介绍，破折号用2条横杠表示，在中国大陆，一般是一条长度差不多和用2条横杠表示的破折号，感觉前面一句话有点难理解的话，你可以简单理解为把2条横杠连接起来，中间没有空隙就是中国大陆常用的破折号。具体的例子看第三张图片中的范例
根据跳转链接来看，从中文版的 https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E7%A0%B4%E6%8A%98%E5%8F%B7 切换到英文版的介绍时，跳转到了 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash
结论
Em_dash表示中文的破折号，中国大陆基本上只说破折号，dash表示连接号，连接号在中国大陆很少用。
作为一个母语为中文的人，如果你说在句子中，破折号是什么，我会毫不犹豫地给出答案，如果你说连接号是什么，我会说我不知道什么是连接号。

The dash is in the form of "——". A dash is a symbol that represents a change in topic or tone, a continuation of voice, etc.

A dash indicates either a 破折号 (em dash, longer than normal dash) or 连接号 (dash) in National Standards of the People's Republic of China.
破折号 is used to "标示语段中某些成分的注释、补充说明或语音、意义的变化" (indicate annotations, supplementary explanations, or changes in pronunciation or meaning of certain elements in the text).
连接号 is used to "标示某些相关联成分之间的连接" (indicate the connections between certain related components). But it has three forms: - (hyphen), ― (horizontal bar) and ～(wave dash).

In Revised Handbook of Punctuation by Taiwanese Ministry of Education, 破折号 is the essentially the same as 破折號.
連接號 is different as it only used to "連接時空的起止或數量的多寡等" (indicate the starting and ending points of time and space, or the quantity or extent). And it has two forms: — and ～.
